# "I'm getting output as <property object at 0x00000242B5F7AF98>". How can I get the value of x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please suggest me the way to get x in the below code.I'm getting the output as `<property object at 0x00000242B5F7AF98>`

```
    from collections import namedtuple
    
    points=namedtuple("points","x y z")
    
    color=namedtuple("color","red blue green")
    
    pixel=namedtuple("pixel",points._fields+color._fields)
    
    pixel(11,12,13,14,15,16)
    
    print(pixel.x)
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the question? Please provide context and format your code with the {} button after reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i've just wanted to print the value of 'x' finally with using the print(pixel.x) iam getting <property object at 0x00000242B5F7AF98> but i want the value    given 11 to print

Comment: I *think* the question here involves a confusion between types and values of that type, but there's not enough information here to even really guess what the question is.

Comment: `pixel` is the **class**, not the **instance** (which is inaccessible because you didn't assign it to anything). Also I think it probably makes more sense for a pixel to have colour and point attributes (*composition*), rather than combining the attributes of both (usually done by *inheritance*, but that's not what you've done here).

Comment: @srinivasreddy: You should [edit] that information into your question.

Comment: tqq @Patrick Haugh

Comment: Remember that [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) returns a type that you can use to *make* `namedtuple`s with the specified properties.

Comment: from collections import namedtuple

points=namedtuple("points","x y z")

color=namedtuple("color","red blue green")

pixel=namedtuple("pixel",points._fields+color._fields)

k=pixel(11,12,13,14,15,16)

print(k.x)

Answer (score 1):

assign `pixel(11,12,13,14,15,16)` to a variable and try it again:

```
variable = pixel(11,12,13,14,15,16)
print(variable.x)
```